# How to handle network failure in paypal Express Checkout after payment?

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal Express Checkout method in my **PHP** site to get the payment from the user. My problem is if i loss the internet connection after the user made the payment in paypal website but if network fails before it reaches back to my website with the result array from where i will get the transaction details like transaction id, amount, etc.,

How to handle this situation?

Comment: If you're doing redirects to the PayPal website, you're not using 'DoDirect' (DoDirectPayment). Please clarify which product you're using, and search SO for 'PayPal IPN'.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I think i corrected my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found answer to my own question which left unanswered for lot of days based on the Robert's comment. Please read [this](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf) complete document to know the complete details.